# how can i add foreign key in laravel without error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, foreign-keys

can you guys help me? I want to add a foreign key in the `posts` table which has a reference in the `categories` table. But when I type the command `php artisan migrate:fresh` it always fails. The error I get is like this `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'handconsulting'.'posts' (errno: 150 "Foreignkey constraint is incorrectly formed")")`

this is my `posts` table

```
 Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('excerpt');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('iamge')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

this is my `categories` table

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Is `posts` schema run before `categories` schema? Check your migration filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my approach:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```